# Scalling up ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a problem with scaling up Elasticsearch.

We have a simple structure with multiple indexes each index has 2 shards, 1 primary and 1 duplicate.
Around now we have ~ 3000 indexes which mean 6000 shards and we think that we will hit limits with shards soon. (currently running 2 nodes 32gb of ram, 4 cores top usage 65%, we are working on changing servers to 3 nodes to have 1 primary shard and 2 duplicates)

Refresh interval is set to 60s.

Some indexes have 200 documents, others have 10 mil documents most of them are less than 200k.
The total amount of documents is: 40 mil. (amount of documents can increase fast)

Our search requests are hitting multiple indexes at the same time (we might be searching in 50 indexes or 500 indexes, we might need in the future to be able to search in all indexes).
Searching need to be fast.

Currently, we are daily synchronizing all documents by bulk in chunks of 5000 of documents ~ 7mb because from tests that is working best ~ 2,3 seconds per request of 5000 ~ 7mb, done by 10 async workers.
We sometimes hit the same index with workers at same time and request with bulk is taking longer extending even to ~ 12,5 sec per request of 5000 ~ 7mb.
Current synchronization process takes about ~1hour / 40 mil of documents.

Documents are stored by uuids (we are using them to get direct hits of documents from elasticsearch), documents values can be modified daily, sometimes we only change `synchronization_hash` which determins which documents were changed, after all the synchronization process we run a delete on documents with old `synchronization_hash`.

Other thing is that we think that our data architecture is broken, we have x clients ~ 300 number can increase, each client is assigned to be only allowed to search in y indexes (from 50 to 500), indexes for multiple clients can repeat in search (client x has 50 indexes, client y has 70 indexes, client y,x most often clients need to have access to same documents in indexes, amount of clients can increase) that's why we store data in separated indexes so we don't have to update all indexes where this data is stored.

To increase a speed of indexing we are thinking even moving to 4 nodes (with each index 2 primary, 2 duplicates), or moving to 4 nodes (with each index only having 2, 1 primary, 1 duplicate), but we need to test things out to figure out what would work for us the best. We might be needing to double amount of documents in next few months.

What do you think can be changed to increase a indexing speed without reducing an search speed?
What can be changed in our data architecture?
Is there any other way that our data should be organized to allow us for fast searching and faster indexing?

I tried many sizes of chunks in synchronization / didn't try to change the architecture.

We are trying to achive increased indexing speed without reducing search speed.

Comment: From how many sources are you synchronzing the data? Is there a possibilty to parallelize this process? I mean sending data to ES from more sources than only one? I had an issue of slow indexing(data was comning from fluentd) till i started running fluentd in multiworker configuration.

Comment: We have one data source and we are sending data by 10 async workers so it is paralel.
Workers have splited synchronization for 200k documents per job, sometimes multiple workers hit same index and request of 5k documents slows down from 2,5 sec to 12,5 sec if 10 workers are sending data to the same index.